# Unidentified LEGO 6 bag set dated 2007, sand, dark grey, and dark red pieces with small dinosaur statues

Tags: set-identification

There's six bags here dated 2007:

[image][image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Most parts are from [7627-1: Temple of the Crystal Skull](http://brickset.com/sets/7627-1/Temple-of-the-Crystal-Skull), based on [Wall Element 1X6X5, Abs](http://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-4512688) and [Limb Element](http://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-4129872),

There are also some parts from [3315-1: Olivia's House](http://brickset.com/sets/3315-1/Olivia-s-House) is the photo's, like: [Wall Element 1X6X5, Abs](http://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-4512688), [Fence 1X4X2 W. 4 Knobs](http://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6047813) & [Flat Tile 1X4](http://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-4164021).